# Allowing remote access to Elasticsearch

Tags: python, security, lucene, debian, elasticsearch

I have a default installation of Elasticsearch which I am trying to query from a third party server. However, it seems that by default this is blocked.

Is anyone please able to tell me how I can configure Elasticsearch so that I can query it from a different server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When elasticsearch is installed and run without any configuration changes by default it binds to localhost only. To access the elasticsearch REST API endpoint remotely the below changes has to be made on the server where elasticsearch has been installed.

- Elasticsearch Configuration Change
  Update the network.host property in elasticsearch.yml as per the guidelines provided in the elasticsearch documentation
  For example to bind to all IPv4 addresses on the local machine, change as below
  network.host : 0.0.0.0
- Firewall Rules Update
  Update the Linux firewall to allow access to port 9200. Please refer your Linux documentation for adding rules to the firewall.

For example to allow access to all the servers(public) in CentosOS use the firewall-cmd

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=9200/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Note : In production environment public access is discouraged. A restricted access should be preferred.

Answer (score 3):

In config/elasticsearch.yml, put network.host: 0.0.0.0.
And also add Inbound Rule in firewall for your ElasticSearch port(9200 ByDefault).
It worked in ElasticSearch version 2.3.0

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: As **Sisso** mentions in his comment below, Elasticsearch as of 2.0 at least binds to localhost by default. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/modules-network.html for more information.

---

As **Damien** mentions in his answer, by default ES allows all access to port `9200`. In fact, you need to use external tools to provide authentication to the ES resource - something like a webapp frontend or just simple nginx with Basic Auth turned on.

Things that can prevent you from accessing a remote system (you probably know these):

- network configuration problems
- ES host firewall blocks incoming requests on port `9200`
- remote host firewall blocks outgoing requests to ES host and/or port `9200`
- ES is configured to bind to the wrong IP address (by default however, it binds to all available IPs)

Best guess? Check that you can connect from remote host to ES host, then check firewall on both systems. If you can't diagnose further, maybe someone on the ES mailing list  (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/elasticsearch) or IRC channel (#elasticsearch on Freenode) can help.

Comment: I don't think that it still true. Current version only binds to localhost.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/modules-network.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no restriction by default, ElasticSearch expose a standard HTTP API on the port `9200`.

From your third party server, are you able to: `curl http://es_hostname:9200/`?

Comment: Damien - you are rite. there's no default restriction.

Comment: There **is** a restriction for IPv4. The standard API answers fine for local tests. Not remote tests.

Comment: From ES > 2.0 there is a new restriction, configure the network.host (you have special keywork like "_local_" and "_site_") now.

Answer (score 1):

To allow remote access with one default node, `settings\elasticsearch.yml` should have:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
```

My case I need three instances. For each instance, it's necessary declare also the port range used.

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200-9202
```